# I have synced two swiper sliders but i want main slider to not scroll when thumb slider is been swiped with touch,

Tags: swiper.js

I have synced two swiper sliders but I want the main slider to not scroll when the thumb slider is swiped with touch but only change with the main slider when clicked on the thumbnail. I also don't want to compromise the free mode of the thumbnail. i am using swiper 8.4.5.  i have this code

```
  var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
   loop: true,
   loopedSlides: 10,
   centeredSlides: true,
   spaceBetween: 10,
   slideToClickedSlide: true,
   slidesPerView: 5,
   watchSlidesVisibility: true,
   watchSlidesProgress: true,
 });

 var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
   loop: true,
   loopedSlides: 10,
   spaceBetween: 10,
   navigation: {
     nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
     prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
   },

  galleryTop.controller.control = galleryThumbs;
// galleryThumbs.controller.control = galleryTop;
```

I have only synced the top slider the thumbnail but how can able click the thumbnail and change the top slider?
here the sample code. (updated example of code)
https://codepen.io/mossawir/pen/BaPxPRz

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution my self. in case any one run into this case. all you need to do is. move the thumbnail code above the main slider code and add thumb: {}
here is the code

```
 var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
   loop: true,
   loopedSlides: 10,
   centeredSlides: true,
   spaceBetween: 10,
   slideToClickedSlide: true,
   slidesPerView: 5,
   watchSlidesVisibility: true,
   watchSlidesProgress: true,
 });

 var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
   loop: true,
   loopedSlides: 10,
   spaceBetween: 10,
   navigation: {
     nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
     prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
   },

   // USING THE THUMBS COMPONENT
    thumbs: {
      swiper: galleryThumbs
    }
 });


 galleryTop.controller.control = galleryThumbs;
 //galleryThumbs.controller.control = galleryTop;
```